# How to prevent Gson serialize / deserialize the first character of a field (underscore)?

Tags: json, parsing, gson

My class:

```
class ExampleBean {
   private String _firstField;
   private String _secondField;
   // respective getters and setters
}
```

I want to appear as follows:

```
{
     "FirstField":"value",
     "SecondField":"value"
}
```

And not like this

```
{
     "_FirstField":"value",
     "_SecondField":"value"
}
```

I initialize the parser as follows:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG);
    builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
    builder.setPrettyPrinting();
    set_defaultParser(builder.create());
```

I could see the [API](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) and in the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support) of "FieldNamePolicy" but I am surprised that not give the option to skip "_"
I also know I can use the annotation...

```
@ SerializedName (" custom_naming ")
```

...but do not want to have to write this for alllllll my fields ...

It's very useful for me to distinguish between local variables and fields of a class. :(  Any Idea?

**EDIT:** There would be many obvious solutions, (inheritance, gson overwriting methods, regular expresions). My question is more focused on whether there is a native solution of gson or a less intrusive fix?

Maybe we could propose as new FieldNamePolicy?

Comment: The answer is ... follow proper Java naming conventions and don't use underscores. And even though JSON naming conventions allow for it, you would rarely find anyone using PascalCase in JSON (which is what your proposed output is). Your other option is using `@SerializedName` for every non-matching field name.

Comment: You did not tell me anything I do not know. Me and my team of professionals, we are free to choose the language conventions that we agree more. Especially when we are integrating various technologies and languages ​​simultaneously. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Then you and your "team of professionals" should be prepared to deal with the problems that arise from that, eh? Oddly enough I was actually in the midst of typing an answer showing you how you can actually accomplish this with a custom Gson JsonSerializer using reflection when you commented ... but I'm sure you'll figure that out, given that you have a whole team of professionals ...

Comment: Relax your ego Brian. I did not mean to upset you. Quiet, I'm sure we'll correct it and share it with the community, if there is not someone to do it before. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Ego? I'm just commenting on the apparent oxymoron of the "team of professionals" asking basic questions on the internet.

Comment: We are professionals (not experts) because we live of it. It's not a hobby for us. Thanks for comment, Brian, really. Hopefully someone will help us into this basic question.

Comment: Fair enough - your answer is below.

Comment: I think that enagra has a valid question. And it's perfectly normal that one might be serializing a class that they didn't write themselves or cannot change. Let's stay objective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`GsonBuilder` provides a method `setFieldNamingStrategy()` that allows you to pass your own `FieldNamingStrategy` implementation.

Note that this replaces the call to `setFieldNamingPolicy()` - if you look at the source for `GsonBuilder` these two methods are mutually exclusive as they set the same internal field (The `FieldNamingPolicy` enum *is a* `FieldNamingStrategy`).

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setFieldNamingStrategy(new MyFieldNamingStrategy())
                        .setPrettyPrinting()
                        .create();

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new ExampleBean()));
    }
}

class ExampleBean
{

    private String _firstField = "first field value";
    private String _secondField = "second field value";
    // respective getters and setters
}

class MyFieldNamingStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy
{
    public String translateName(Field field)
    {
        String fieldName = 
            FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE.translateName(field);
        if (fieldName.startsWith("_"))
        {
            fieldName = fieldName.substring(1);
        }
        return fieldName;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "FirstField": "first field value",
  "SecondField": "second field value"
}
```

Comment: I attempted to edit this so that it compiles and works, but the edit was rejected. There isn't a translateName() method on FieldNamingPolicy.  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5997458

Comment: @Kirby there is, since version 1.3 https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html

Comment: We have lots of field with locale added field_en_us, field_zh_tw. I had been writing custom deserializers on those for 2 years now. Removed all those. This is very helpful!!!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.text.DateFormat;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonExample {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG);
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        builder.setFieldNamingStrategy(new FieldNamingStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String translateName(Field f) {
                String fieldName = f.getName();
                if(fieldName.startsWith("_") && fieldName.length() > 1) {
                    fieldName = fieldName.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(2);
                }
                return fieldName;
            }
        });
        final Gson gson = builder.create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new ExampleBean("example", "bean")));
    }


    private static class ExampleBean {
        private final String _firstField;
        private final String _secondField;

        private ExampleBean(String _firstField, String _secondField) {
            this._firstField = _firstField;
            this._secondField = _secondField;
        }
    }
}
```

which generates

```
{"FirstField":"example","SecondField":"bean"}
```